# Problems with reading blob field - out of memory

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-7, pdfium

I have an application in Delphi 7, where I made the code below to load large PDF files from a blob field to memory and then I load the PDF, it works perfect with large files I have already tested with 1 gigabyte files.
However, somewhere there is a memory leak and I don't know where, after loading 10 large files, it presents the Message - Out of Memory.

I am not sure how to clear the memory after loading the memory.

I already tested loading several pdf files and it works perfectly, the component has no problem.
Note guys, I don't want to save it to file after loading it in the component, I want to do it directly in memory.

Note guys, I don't want to save to file on disk and then load the component, I want to do it directly in memory.

```
procedure TForm1.btnAbrirClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  BlobStream: TStream;
  Arquivo: Pointer;
begin
  pdf2.Active := False;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    BlobStream := absqry1.CreateBlobStream(absqry1.FieldByName('binario'),bmRead);
    Arquivo := AllocMem(BlobStream.Size);
    BlobStream.Position := 0;
    BlobStream.ReadBuffer(Arquivo^, BlobStream.Size);
    pdf2.LoadDocument(Arquivo);
    pdfvw1.Active := True;
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    BlobStream.Free;
    Arquivo := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arquivo := nil;` does not free memory allocated by `AllocMem`. For that, you need a call to `FreeMem`.

This is covered in the documentation (**emphasis** mine):

> AllocMem allocates a memory block and initializes each byte to zero.
>
> AllocMem allocates a block of the given Size on the heap, and returns the address of this memory. Each byte in the allocated buffer is set to zero. **To dispose of the buffer, use FreeMem.** If there is not enough memory available to allocate the block, an EOutOfMemory exception is raised.

I've also corrected your use of `try..finally`.

```
procedure TForm1.btnAbrirClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  BlobStream: TStream;
  Arquivo: Pointer;
begin
  pdf2.Active := False;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  BlobStream := absqry1.CreateBlobStream(absqry1.FieldByName('binario'),bmRead);
  try
    Arquivo := AllocMem(BlobStream.Size);
    try
      BlobStream.Position := 0;
      BlobStream.ReadBuffer(Arquivo^, BlobStream.Size);
      pdf2.LoadDocument(Arquivo);
      pdfvw1.Active := True;
    finally
      FreeMem(Arquivo);
    end;
 finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    BlobStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't be [GetMem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.GetMem) more appropriate for this scenario?

Comment: @PeterWolf GetMem() won't fill with Zeros, so may be faster for small blocks. But for huge blocks (>256KB), FastMM4 just call the Windows VirtualAlloc() API which already set with zeros. So it won't be faster in practice.

Comment: I used to do it the way you taught me before, but I had problems with memory errors.
I got a response from the component's author who explained that I could only clear the memory when the component is inactive.
Then I changed the time to clear the memory, after pdf2.Active: = False; which is correct, now it's working 100%
Thank you very much for your help and explanation.